# What does @UndefinedVariable stand for in Python?

Tags: python, comments, python-decorators

I came across the `# @UndefinedVariable` tag in [this](https://github.com/NightNord/ljd/blob/master/ljd/rawdump/code.py) script. Does this comment have any meaning during execution?

Comment: No, it has no meaning to *Python*.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? A clear question and, although it may seem obvious, surely a reasonable question for a novice to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that text has no meaning to Python.  It is in a comment, and *comments never reach the runtime*.

Currently, the Python *language* assigns meaning to one comment type, the [source encoding declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). The comment has meaning to the tokeniser only. It is not retained either, and isn't available at runtime, it only influences how the tokeniser reads the source code before parsing and compiling into bytecode.

That the text contains an `@` is neither here nor there, it is not related to the Python decorator syntax; it probably is something completely different. For example, there are several documentation systems that use `@` to denote special meaning to text; javadoc being a prime example. The text *probably* has meaning to an external tool that parses the source code for their own needs.

Comment: That 'external tool' is apparently PyDev http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_assistants.html

Comment: The '@' at the beginning of the comment confused me. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Those comments are most likely added there by the PyDev editor. It's very specific to that editor and is not part of the python language. It's basically a comment that tells PyDev's code assistant to not complain about that line.

There are other other tools such as `pyflakes` that looks for comments with specific content.

This is mostly used by tools analysing the code.

Comment: When I googled @UndefinedVariable, I found many pages where PyDev was mentioned, indeed.

Comment: @dada Indeed. You will probably also see a lot of `# flake8: noqa` and `# noqa` around. That's comments telling the pyflakes library to ignore parts of the code when it tests for pep8 compliance: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/